# Chrome's aggressive caching

Tags: google-chrome, caching

Since I've implemented my cache manifest to cache a couple of things I've noticed that Chrome started aggressively caching everything and I find myself having to force delete the cache from `chrome://appcache-internals/` because CTRL-F5, CTRL-R won't work even if I press them repeatedly.

This is my cache manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
/static/sound.wav

NETWORK:
*
```

Have you experienced this problem? What options do I have to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I have never heard of anyone describing caching as "stahkanovist"...interesting choice of words.

Comment: I think if you have an appcache, you need to change the manifest. Then load the page to download the manifest, and refresh to view the updated version... (maybe it's not such a good idea to use appcache under development)